# AWS - can we set Environment variable to read inside Docker?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can we set Environment variable against an EC2 instance from AWS console?
Or do we need load any other service to achieve this?

Also can we load this variable insider Docker?

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be out of scope for the [AWS Console](https://aws.amazon.com/console/). EC2 however is basically AWS hosted VMs, So anything you could do normally on that OS can be [done](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html).

Just connect to the machine and do what you would normally do. (See the AWS CLI [Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html) for further help)

Answer (score 0):

Using the AWS Console:

- Stop the ec2 instance
- For that ec2 instance, from top dropdown - select Actions > Instance Settings > View/Change User Data
- Create a script that would add required environment variables to init scripts.

## !/bin/sh echo 'export MY_ENV_VARIABLE=value' >> ~/.bashrc

or a script to /etc/init.d or other similar locations..

- Start the EC2 instance for the Environment variables to be available.

If you want to pass the EC2 instance environment variable to the Docker container environment variable:

When you start a docker instance through "docker run" you can pass the value through --env param in the command line.

eg: docker run -e DOCKER_ENV_VARIABLE=$MY_ENV_VARIABLE ...

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options

Answer (score 0):

You can use *user_data* to load and afterwards pass to your docker container using `docker run -e CONTAINER_ENV_VAR=$EC2_ENV_VAR`or put in your Dockerfile.

for keys or any sensitive data I would advise you to use the Parameter Store, you can put passwords, users, or whatever data you want and use a service call `chamber`